# Pygame Executable Crashing

Tags: pygame, pyinstaller

I have a small animation code that is built using PyGame (and Python 2.7). I am able to build the executable folder with Pyinstaller, however when I try to run the executable it is crashing, although I am able to run the same files (i.e. source code) through my terminal without any problem.

```
import pygame
import exercise
import random as rd
import copy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def animate():
    debug_mode=False

    done1 = False

    dc_x = 30
    dc_y = 30
    plant_x = 110
    plant_y = 30
    supp_x = 190
    supp_y = 30

    WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
    BLACK = (0, 0, 0) #arrows
    RED = (255, 0, 0) # Box frames for summary of t, cost and lost sales
    GREEN = (0, 255, 0) # Box frames for shipment amounts
    DEEPSKYBLUE = (0,191,255)  # arc to represent backup WIP inv
    DOGERBLUE = (0,191,255)  # arc to represent backup FG inv
    INDIGO = (75,0,130)  # DC/Supp up state
    LAVENDER=(238, 130, 238) #DC/Supp down state
    OLIVE=(128,128,0) #plant down state
    YELLOWGREEN=(173,255,47) #plant up state
    DARKYELLOW=(204,204,0)

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    grand_record={}
    ############ READ AND PREPARE INITIAL SCREEN for t==0 ################
    PLANT_status, SUPP_status, DC_status, disruption, DC_BUp_Plan, Plant_BUp_Plan, Supp_BUp_Plan, Demand, P=exercise.init(debug_mode,False)
    grand_record[0]={"DC":DC_status, "Plant":PLANT_status, "Supplier":SUPP_status}

    basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)
    largeFont = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)
    pygame.display.set_caption('SCREAM!')
    if debug_mode: R=1
    else: R= rd.randint(0,25)
    scenario_score={"cost":0, "service":0}


    while not done1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done1 = True
            #if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            #        paused()
        end_of_one_run=1
        total_lost_customer=0
        cumulative_inv_holding_cost=0
        total_fixed_cost_paid=0
        table_output=[]
        chart_output=[]
        header=["Week","Demand","Upstream shipment", "Shipment from regular DC", "Shipment from backup DC",
                "FG Inv at Reg. DC", "FG Inv at B/up. DC", "FG Inv as B/up","LostSales","Start Order for b/up DC", "B/up DC starts","DC Disruption at","Disruption duration", "TotalAvailableWIPSupplyCap",
                "Start Order for b/up Supplier", "B/up Supplier starts","Supplier Disruption at","Disruption duration", "Storage Cap Available", "Plant production",
                 "WIP Inv as B/up","Start Order for b/up Plant", "B/up Plant starts","Plant Disruption at","Disruption duration"]
        table_output.append(header)
        for t in range(1,P+1): # for the specified number of periods
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            picture = pygame.image.load('Background.png').convert() #MITwallpaper
            screen.blit(picture, [0, 0])
            #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            ################################## MAKE CALCULATIONS FOR t>0 ################
            grand_record,output=exercise.calculate(t, grand_record[t-1]["Plant"], grand_record[t-1]["Supplier"], grand_record[t-1]["DC"], disruption, DC_BUp_Plan, Plant_BUp_Plan,  Supp_BUp_Plan,Demand[R*P+t],grand_record,debug_mode)
            chart_output=exercise.prepare_chart_output(chart_output, grand_record)
            output_loc=copy.deepcopy(output)
            table_output.append(output_loc)
            end_of_one_run=end_of_one_run+1

            objectives=exercise.calculate_objectives(grand_record, DC_BUp_Plan, Plant_BUp_Plan, Supp_BUp_Plan, t)

            lost_cust_text = largeFont.render("Service: "+str(objectives["Service"]), True, WHITE, BLACK)
            lost_cust_textRect = lost_cust_text.get_rect()
            lost_cust_textRect.centerx = 380
            lost_cust_textRect.centery = 420
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (lost_cust_textRect.left - 3, lost_cust_textRect.top - 3, lost_cust_textRect.width + 3, lost_cust_textRect.height + 3))
            screen.blit(lost_cust_text, lost_cust_textRect)
            inv_hold_text = largeFont.render("Inv.Holding Cost(k$): "+str(round(objectives["InvHoldingCost"]*0.001,1)), True, WHITE, BLACK)
            inv_hold_textRect = inv_hold_text.get_rect()
            inv_hold_textRect.centerx = 600
            inv_hold_textRect.centery = 445
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (inv_hold_textRect.left - 3, inv_hold_textRect.top - 3, inv_hold_textRect.width + 3, inv_hold_textRect.height + 3))
            screen.blit(inv_hold_text, inv_hold_textRect)
            startup_text = largeFont.render("Startup Cost(k$): "+str(round(objectives["Startup_cost"]*0.001,1)), True, WHITE, BLACK)
            startup_textRect = startup_text.get_rect()
            startup_textRect.centerx = 840
            startup_textRect.centery = 470
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (startup_textRect.left - 3, startup_textRect.top - 3, startup_textRect.width + 3, startup_textRect.height + 3))
            screen.blit(startup_text, startup_textRect)

            ###################################################################################
            if t<P:
                pygame.display.flip()
                clock.tick(8)
            else:
                #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
                table = pd.DataFrame(table_output)
                table.to_excel("Details.xlsx",index=False)

        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        done1 = True
    ################################ Want A PARETO Button     ###################################
    x=500
    y=500
    w=200
    h=50
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, DEEPSKYBLUE,(x,y,w,h))
    buttontext = basicFont.render("Want A Pareto Solution?", True, BLACK , WHITE )
    buttontext_rect=buttontext.get_rect()
    buttontext_rect.centerx = (x+(w/2))
    buttontext_rect.centery = (y+(h/2))
    screen.blit(buttontext, buttontext_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.time.delay(120)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    exercise.plotcharts(chart_output)
################################################################################
animate()
```

Comment: how are you using pyinstaller? any command line arguments? If the pygame code is reasonably small that could also be helpful

Comment: I have added the code. There are some external dependencies but they are returning some values or plotting to the local folder.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (also Python 2.7), and this did it for me:

pyinstaller usually has trouble with `pygame.font.SysFont("some_font", 24)`

Instead use `pygame.font.Font("your_own_font.ttf", 24)`.
Download a font and either put it in the same folder as your file, or in a data folder. 
I use VeraMono and put it in a data folder, so my code would be

```
...
basicFont = pygame.font.Font("data/VeraMono", 24)
largeFont = pygame.font.Font("data/VeraMono", 35)
pygame.display.set_caption('SCREAM!')
...
```

If you don't have a data/ folder added to your project yet, then add the following lines to your spec file (the spec file is created as soon as you run you pyinstaller the first time. It has the same name as your python file.)

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

# This entry is new!
added_files = [
    ( 'data', 'data'),
    ]

a = Analysis(['CleanTest.py'],
         pathex=['/home/angela/Desktop/Arbeit/VisualTest'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=added_files,   # add the new file to your data tree
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
...
```

Run `pyinstaller <your_file>.spec`, and hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that it crashes when trying to load the background image:

```
picture = pygame.image.load('Background.png').convert() #MITwallpaper
```

When pyinstaller compiles your code, that is all it compiles (including the imported dependencies). It creates the dist directory where you can run your executable and you are good to go.

But, by default, pyinstaller will not pull in external resources. So when you run the executable, it can't find your image because it is in a different directory. You can test this by manually copying the image to the folder where the exe is located and see if it works.

Also, you can run the exe and push the output into a debug file:

```
your_file.exe > debug.txt
```

This way you can capture the output from your program (including error messages).

Comment: First thing you have said (image uploading) is something I also thought possible and tried. Unfortunately it is not the cause-i.e. When I copy the figure inside folder of .exe it just repeats crashing.

Comment: However I am willing to try the debug. txt file. how can I apply that exactly?

Comment: In the terminal type:  your.exe > debug.txt (debug is just a name just chose, it can be anything)

Comment: It just printed "Untested Windows version 10 is detected" and then crashed again with  an empty 'debug.txt' generated   .

Comment: ah, what are your versions of pyinstaller, python and windows?

Comment: windows 10; python 2.7; pyinstaller should be the most recent one

Comment: @Ozgu, ok, without knowing anything else, I would check the following: Try it with python 3.5. Also be sure you have the proper bit version of it. I need to use Python 3.5 32-bit for example. You need to make sure the versions of each of these things match whether your system is 32 or 64 bit

Comment: @Ozgu and if nothing works, I have reached the scope of my knowledge. I would try asking another question, but include all the information regarding the error, what you tried, and the versions of all software included. The more thorough you can be, the more likely someone can answer your questions